2 dimensional Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+c^2)^{3/2}}$
I'm trying to calculate the 2D Fourier transform of this function:
$$\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+c^2)^{3/2}}$$,
where $x$ and $y$ are independent variables and $c$ is a positive constant,
I know the answer should look like $\frac{ik_{x}}{k}$ where $k^{2}=k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}$.
I found something related to but not exactly, could someone help? thank you!

Possibly a hint: consider the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  (x^2+y^2+c^2)^{-1/2}$.

thanks! this really helps!

Denoting $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}$, and using $F[\frac1r]=\frac{4\pi}{k^2}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ik_xx+k_yy}}{(x^2+y^2+c^2)^{3/2}}dxdy\overset{IBP}{=}ik_x\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ik_xx+k_yy}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2}}dxdy$$
$$=\frac{ik_x}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ik_xx+k_yy+ik_z(z-c)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2}}dxdydzdk_z=2ik_x\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ik_zc}}{k^2}dk_z$$
$$=2\pi i\frac{k_xe^{-c\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}$$

Let $f_1(x,y,c)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2}}$
and $f(x,y,c)=\frac{\partial f_1(x,y,c)}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2+c^2\right)^{3/2}}$
Then the fourier transform (unitary, angular frequency) $$F_1(\omega_1,\omega_2,c)=\mathcal{F}_{x,y}[f_1(x,y,c)]\left(\omega _1,\omega _2\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }-\frac{e^ {-i (\omega_1 x+\omega_2 y)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2}}dxdy=-\frac{e^{-c \sqrt{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}}}{\sqrt{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}}$$
Hence the fourier transform of the derivative is
$$\mathcal{F}_{x,y}[\text{f}(x,y,c)]\left(\omega _1,\omega _2\right)= i\omega_1\cdot F_1(\omega_1,\omega_2,c)=-i\omega_1\cdot\frac{e^{-c \sqrt{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}}}{\sqrt{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}}$$

Using $\frac{1}{A^{3/2}}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sA}\frac{s^{1/2}}{\Gamma(3/2)}ds$ you land on the integral $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{a}{s}-bs}\frac{ds}{s^{1/2}}$ which is classical.
